# Java Apache Spark Streaming

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am working on Realtime Event Processing as part of my assignment. I am getting a live stream of data in form of a nested json using java http request to a server. After getting this data, I am using **Gson** to convert Json to java where I have two separate classes that have attributes to work with the data. My problem is that I want to create **JavaRDD**s with this data so that I can perform transformations on it. Some websites are suggesting using DataFrames.

Here is the code snippet.

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class BusArrivalData implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String arrivaldatetime;
    private int duetime;
    private String departuredatetime;
    private String departureduetime;
    private String scheduledarrivaldatetime;
    private String scheduleddeparturedatetime;
    private String destination;
    private String destinationlocalized;
    private String origin;
    private String originlocalized;
    private String direction;
    private String operator;
    private String additionalinformation;
    private String lowfloorstatus;
    private int route;
    private String sourcetimestamp;
    private boolean monitored;

    //getters and setters

    public BusArrivalData() {
        super();
    }
}
```

another class attached to **Gson**

```
package data.analyt;

public class BusStopData implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String stopid;
    private String timestamp;
    private String errorcode;
    private String errormessage;
    private Integer numberofresults;

    List<BusArrivalData> results;

    public BusStopData() {

    }

    public BusStopData(String stopid, String timestamp) {
        super();
        this.stopid = stopid;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }
}
```

making a http request for the **Json** and using **Gson**

```
   import java.io.BufferedReader;
   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.io.InputStreamReader;
   import java.io.Serializable;
   import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
   import java.net.MalformedURLException;
   import java.net.URL;
   import java.security.KeyManagementException;
   import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
   import java.security.SecureRandom;
   import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
   import java.util.Iterator;
   import java.util.List;

   import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
   import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
   import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
   import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;

   import com.google.gson.Gson;

   import scala.Tuple2;

   import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext;
   import org.apache.spark.streaming.Duration;
   import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaDStream;
   import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext;
   import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
   import org.apache.spark.SparkContext;
   import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
   import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
   import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function;
   import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame;

   public class Connection implements Serializable{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private static String output;
public static BusStopData bsd;
public static List<BusArrivalData> cd; 



public static void responseConnection() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {
    TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{new X509TrustManager(){
        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers(){return null;}
        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType){}
        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType){}
    }};

     try {
            SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new SecureRandom());
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
            URL url = new URL("https://data.dublinked.ie/cgi-bin/rtpi/realtimebusinformation?stopid=45&routeid=1&format=json");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

            if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                        + conn.getResponseCode());
            }

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                (conn.getInputStream())));

            System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
            while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(output);

                bsd = new Gson().fromJson(output, BusStopData.class);
                cd = bsd.getResults();  
            }

            conn.disconnect();

            System.out.println("Bus Stop ID: " + bsd.getStopid());
            System.out.println("No of Results: " + bsd.getNumberofresults());
            System.out.println("TimeStamp: " + bsd.getTimestamp());
            System.out.println("Results Size: " + cd.size());
            System.out.println(bsd.getResults().iterator().next().getScheduledarrivaldatetime());

            for (Iterator iterator = cd.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
                BusArrivalData busArrivalData = (BusArrivalData) iterator.next();   
                System.out.println("Departure Times: " +busArrivalData.getDeparturedatetime());             
            }

            //=========TODO============


          } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

          } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

          }

     SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf()
             .setAppName("Example")
             .setMaster("local[*]");

     JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
     SQLContext sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc);

     DataFrame df = sqlContext.read().json(output);
     df.select(
                df.col("stopid"),
                df.col("timestamp"),
                org.apache.spark.sql.functions.explode(df.col("results")).as("results")
            );
     df.show();

}
```

}

Runner Class

```
    /**
 *
 */
     import java.io.BufferedReader;
     import java.io.IOException;
     import java.io.InputStreamReader;
     import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
     import java.net.MalformedURLException;
     import java.net.URL;
     import java.security.KeyManagementException;
     import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
     import java.security.SecureRandom;
     import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
     import java.util.Iterator;
     import java.util.List;

     import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
     import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
     import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
     import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;

     import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
     import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
     import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
     import org.apache.spark.streaming.Duration;
     import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext;

     import com.google.gson.Gson;


     public class App 
     {


         public static void main( String[] args ) throws Throwable
         {
           Connection.responseConnection();

         }

    }
```

Output result

```
{"errorcode":"0","errormessage":"","numberofresults":2,"stopid":"45","timestamp":"06\/02\/2017 22:41:13","results":[{"arrivaldatetime":"06\/02\/2017 23:08:38","duetime":"27","departuredatetime":"06\/02\/2017 23:08:38","departureduetime":"27","scheduledarrivaldatetime":"06\/02\/2017 23:09:00","scheduleddeparturedatetime":"06\/02\/2017 23:09:00","destination":"Sandymount","destinationlocalized":"Dumhach Thrá ","origin":"Shanard Road","originlocalized":" ","direction":"Outbound","operator":"bac","additionalinformation":"","lowfloorstatus":"no","route":"1","sourcetimestamp":"06\/02\/2017 22:08:58","monitored":"true"},{"arrivaldatetime":"06\/02\/2017 23:36:54","duetime":"55","departuredatetime":"06\/02\/2017 23:36:54","departureduetime":"55","scheduledarrivaldatetime":"06\/02\/2017 23:37:00","scheduleddeparturedatetime":"06\/02\/2017 23:37:00","destination":"O'Connell Street","destinationlocalized":"Sráid Uí Chonaill ","origin":"Shanard Road","originlocalized":" ","direction":"Outbound","operator":"bac","additionalinformation":"","lowfloorstatus":"no","route":"1","sourcetimestamp":"06\/02\/2017 22:37:02","monitored":"true"}]}

Bus Stop ID: 45
No of Results: 2
TimeStamp: 06/02/2017 22:41:13
Results Size: 2
06/02/2017 23:09:00
Departure Times: 06/02/2017 23:08:38
Departure Times: 06/02/2017 23:36:54
```

I have an object of the type BusStopData that makes use of the **getters** and **setters** to print these results. How can I be able to get this data into **JavaRDDS** or DataFrames if possible... making use of JavaContextStreaming or JavaReceiverInputDStream.

I can send the entire source code if there needs be. Thanks

Comment: It will be helpful if you can provide full source code along with some sample of your data

Comment: @siddhartha jain...if you dont mind, I will edit the source that I posted already. My sample data comes from this url:  https://data.dublinked.ie/cgi-bin/rtpi/realtimebusinformation?stopid=45&routeid=1&format=json

Comment: DStream has a forEachRDD method. From an RDD, you can build your own Dataframe, however I see no streaming here. You only fetch the URL data once, not listen on any TCP socket